# How to insert a deleted element at the original position in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the below code:

1. First I create an array of 10 elements
2. Next I remove 3 random elements from that array.
3. I try to add those 3 random elements into the original array in the original positions.

For some reason in step 3 above (in the `FINAL ARR` console log), the elements are being added in the wrong position. Is my slice function incorrect in step 3? If so, how do I modify it to be correct?

```js
// Step 1. Create array of 10 elements
const originalValues = maxAmount => {
  let finalArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < maxAmount; i++) {
    finalArray.push({
      key1: `key1-${i+1}`,
      position: i
    });
  }
  return finalArray;
}
let finalArr = originalValues(10);
const finalArrOriginalLength = finalArr.length;

//Step 2. Remove 3 random elements in this case key1-2, key1-7, key1-8
const removedElements = [];
finalArr = finalArr.filter(elem => {
  if (elem.key1 === 'key1-7' || elem.key1 === 'key1-2' || elem.key1 === 'key1-8') {
    removedElements.push(elem);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});

/* Step 3. Add those 3 elements back to the original positions */
removedElements.forEach(elem => {
  finalArr.splice(elem.position - (finalArrOriginalLength - finalArr.length) + 1, 0, elem);
});

/* The inserted elements from step 3 are being inserted in the wrong position as seen when this console.log prints out finalArr */
console.log('FINAL ARR', finalArr);
```

Comment: When you remove elements from an array, the indexes of all the following elements are changed. So you can't use the original indexes on the filtered array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to subtract from `elem.position`.

If you sort the removed elements by the original positions, you should be able to insert them at those positions.

This assumes there haven't been any other changes to the array.

```js
// Step 1. Create array of 10 elements
const originalValues = maxAmount => {
  let finalArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < maxAmount; i++) {
    finalArray.push({
      key1: `key1-${i+1}`,
      position: i
    });
  }
  return finalArray;
}
let finalArr = originalValues(10);
const finalArrOriginalLength = finalArr.length;

//Step 2. Remove 3 random elements in this case key1-2, key1-7, key1-8
const removedElements = [];
finalArr = finalArr.filter(elem => {
  if (elem.key1 === 'key1-7' || elem.key1 === 'key1-2' || elem.key1 === 'key1-8') {
    removedElements.push(elem);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});

/* Step 3. Add those 3 elements back to the original positions */
removedElements.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position).forEach(elem => {
  finalArr.splice(elem.position, 0, elem);
});

console.log('FINAL ARR', finalArr);
```

Comment: Ah ok. But what if I want to add one of those removed elements at a time? Then I would be calling the sort function 3 times right which isn't performant?

Comment: This only works if you're inserting all of them. You need to sort because the position of the second element won't be correct unless you insert the first element.

Comment: Got it. How would you do it if we wanted to insert one of those elements at a time?

Comment: You need to count how many of the other removed elements were before the one you're inserting. Then subtract that count from the position.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I used this: `elem.position - (finalArrOriginalLength - finalArr.length)` but didn't seem to work.

Comment: The lengths have nothing to do with it. If you want to add back the element at position 5, you need to count the number of elements in `removedElements` where `position < 5`. Then insert at `elem.position - thatCount`

Comment: And once you add it back, you need to remove it from `removedElements` so that future counts will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
// Step 1. Create array of 10 elements
const originalValues = maxAmount => {
  let finalArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < maxAmount; i++) {
    finalArray.push({
      key1: `key1-${i+1}`,
      position: i
    });
  }
  return finalArray;
}
let finalArr = originalValues(10);
const finalArrOriginalLength = finalArr.length;

//Step 2. Remove 3 random elements in this case key1-2, key1-7, key1-8
const removedElements = [];
finalArr = finalArr.filter(elem => {
  if (elem.key1 === 'key1-7' || elem.key1 === 'key1-2' || elem.key1 === 'key1-8') {
    removedElements.push(elem);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});

// Step 3. Add those 3 elements back to the original positions

removedElements
.sort((a,b)=>{return a.position > b.position ? 0 : 1 });

removedElements.forEach(elem => {
  finalArr.splice(elem.position, 0, elem);
});

/* The inserted elements from step 3 are being inserted in the wrong position as seen when this console.log prints out finalArr */
console.log('FINAL ARR', finalArr);
```

Comment: ...or even better use a sparse array for removed elements. eg insert them at their original source index position so tat you don't need to sort them 'ever again! :d' .